# iOS 6 Custom Font Issues with Core Text

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, core-text

**Background:**

I have a word processing app that utilizes a set of Custom fonts; there are four fonts in my set: Regular, Italic, Bold, & Bold Italic. They are True Type: Open Type formatted. This has been working great in the store for several months with iOS 5.0 & 5.1.

Note: I'm utilizing CoreText and doing all of my own text processing and rendering.

**Issue:**

After upgrading to iOS 6, I noticed that all Italic text is now Bold Italic, and any Bold Italic text is now "undefined" (for me that defaults to another font).

I had hoped that it was just an Xcode issue/change, but it's showing up on my shipped build as well.

**What I've Tried:**

- I've double checked that all the parameters being passed into CTFontCreateWithFontDescriptor are the same between versions.
- Looked through iOS 6.0 & Xcode 4.5 release notes & checked dev forums.
- Removed and re-added Fonts to project

Any assistance or possible places to investigate would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are the right attributes maintained if an Apple font family is specified instead?

Comment: Yes, if I switch to Courier (closest default Font) it works fine. In fact, I currently have a workaround in place to swap out my font before render for Courier. It's not perfect, but its good enough for now so I can get it patched for the App Store version.